# How to resolve Vyper installation error: fatal error: leveldb/db.h

Tags: vyper

Created a virtualenv with python3.6 and performed the following steps

```
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/vyper.git
cd vyper
make
```

I see following error(s):

```
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/7b/9302e33972c4af861f5a425cb37468b4dbb17d7a4d282a657bfdb240055e/plyvel-1.0.4.tar.gz#sha256=134e78519403a6f71f1e66df945763413c48d0f6dec02e1a61f55adf0f83106d
Best match: plyvel 1.0.4
Processing plyvel-1.0.4.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-hqyngt9f/plyvel-1.0.4/setup.cfg
Running plyvel-1.0.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-hqyngt9f/plyvel-1.0.4/egg-dist-tmp-hpr0sci6
warning: no files found matching 'plyvel/*.pxi'
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
plyvel/_plyvel.cpp:547:24: fatal error: leveldb/db.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'init' failed
make: *** [init] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed all the dependencies correctly ? You may also be missing `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` variables (You have not mentioned the platform)

I wrote [this](https://mandarvaze.bitbucket.io/posts/vyper-on-pyenv-virtualenv/) blog post based on my experience. See if it helps.

There is also a link to [this](https://github.com/ltfschoen/vyper/blob/master/README_MAC.md#chapter-0) troubleshooting document (referenced  from my blog as well.)

Comment: Thanks @mandarvaze will review the link that you shared and will update if it fixes.